# BigQuery - how to sort query results based on array element

Tags: google-bigquery

I run the following query:

```
with x AS(
select agent_id, array_agg(struct(price_range as level, sales)) as price_range
from(select agent_id, price_range, count(*) sales
     from (select 1 as agent_id, 'b' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'c' as price_range
           union all
           select 2 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range)
     group by 1,2)
     group by 1)

select * from x
```

I would like to get the results sorted first by the agent_id and then by price_range level.
The thing is that if i unnest() the array first i get a cross join results.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: But price_range.level contains multiple values - how is the sorting supposed to decide for any given row based on multiple elements? Use the maximum level? Or the quantity of elements? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I sort the sub query results before constructing the array, than i get what i wanted.

```
with x AS(
select agent_id, array_agg(struct(price_range as level, sales)) as price_range
from(select agent_id, price_range, count(*) sales
     from (select 1 as agent_id, 'b' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'c' as price_range
           union all
           select 2 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range)
     group by 1,2
     order by 1,2) -- this additional line solved the issue
     group by 1)

select * from x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in your `order by` to aggregate the array to value that helps you sort the row. In this example I use a sorting + limit 1 on the array to sort outside of the array.

```sql
with x AS(
select agent_id, array_agg(struct(price_range as level, sales)) as price_range
from(select agent_id, price_range, count(*) sales
     from (select 1 as agent_id, 'b' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'c' as price_range
           union all
           select 2 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range)
     group by 1,2)
     group by 1)

select * 
from x
order by (select level from unnest(price_range) order by level desc limit 1) asc
-- same as
-- order by (select max(level) from unnest(price_range)) asc
```

You can also sort by counting elements in the array or do some other aggregation

```sql
with x AS(
select agent_id, array_agg(struct(price_range as level, sales)) as price_range
from(select agent_id, price_range, count(*) sales
     from (select 1 as agent_id, 'b' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range
           union all
           select 1 as agent_id, 'c' as price_range
           union all
           select 2 as agent_id, 'a' as price_range)
     group by 1,2)
     group by 1)

select * 
from x
order by (select COUNT(*) from unnest(price_range)) asc
-- same as:
-- order by array_length(price_range) asc
```